# How to export CSV report with self-defined paramters

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

Under Firebase Console->Analytics->Events, users can download a complete CSV report for all event items listed below.

According to the documents, Firebase also provides the functionality for users to modify the parameters for each event item. Users can add multiple self-defined parameters by as needed.

However, the downloaded report only contains the basic fields for each event, such as name, count, user number and conversion rate.

How can I add the self-defined parameters into the downloaded report?

Comment: Hmmm... I don't think there's a way to modify the contents of the CSV export at the moment. If the information you need is not in there, your only option is to enable exporting the analytics data to BigQuery and get it from there. You might also want to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for the data to be added to the CSV.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sigh... What a pity. It would be a pretty useful feature. Anyway, thanks for your reply.